# Does C# have something like a Pascal canvas?

Tags: c#, drawing

In Pascal it is pretty easy to draw lines and realise something like [turtle graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_graphics) because you can draw right on the form. After trying to find something related in C# fon r quite a while now I did not come across anything useful. My questions are:

- Is there any way in C# to manage this task as it is in Pascal?
- If not what "standard" other solutions can I use to implement such a turtle?

Comment: My Pascal days are long long gone. Assuming Winforms you should first look into the drawing model, ie into the `Paint` event. Here you find the Graphics surface (as the `e.Graphics` parameter) of whichever Control or Form you want to draw on. You can draw directly but really should instead collect draw actions lists and have them drawn in the `Paint` by `Invalidating` the control or Form. People most often draw on Panels but almost all Controls can be drawn on.

Comment: If I remember correctly the VCL canvas did take care of the redrawing, right? One way to do that other than scripting the Paint event with lists of thing to draw, would be to draw onto the `Image` of a `PictureBox`. This Control will also safekeep its graphics. Look it up, many examples around here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the `OnPaint` on your form and then you can use the graphics object off of the `PaintEventArgs` to draw on the form:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, new Rectangle(0,0,20,20));
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, 20,20,30,30);
    e.Graphics.DrawIcon(this.Icon, new Rectangle(30,30,30,30));
}
```

Which yields a form that looks like this:

[image: Sample]

Comment: why override when you are calling the base anyway?

Comment: @TaW The docs state to do this for other registered delegates that may need the event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @TaW Form1 derives from `Form`.  If you add an event handler for `Paint` by placing `this.Paint += Form1_Paint;` in the form load, you will see that the event handler only gets called if the base `OnPaint` method is called in the OnPaint override.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WinForms, take a look at this example on MSDN which shows how to draw straight on to a form using `System.Drawing.Graphics`

[How to: Draw a Filled Rectangle on a Windows Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ztxk24yx(v=vs.110).aspx)

This code sample is straight from that link:

```
System.Drawing.SolidBrush myBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics;
formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
formGraphics.FillRectangle(myBrush, new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 300));
myBrush.Dispose();
formGraphics.Dispose();
```